# Source for learning Functional derivative , Gateaux derivative

Tags: optimization, optimal-control

I have started doing research in optimal control theory. My area of research is PDE constrained optimization.

I am facing significant difficulty in deriving the Gateaux Derivative of functionals required for optimization.

For example I have to find out $U(\sigma,u,w;C) = 1/2 \int (\sigma - C:\epsilon[u]):{C}^{-1}:(\sigma - C:\epsilon[u]))$, where $C$ is a 4th order constitutive tensor and $\sigma$ is 2nd order stress tensor. The operator $:$ is the double dot product operator. All quantities are function of space ($R^3$).

How can I calculate derivative of $U$ with respect to $\sigma$ ?? I have tried to expand this using index notation. But it made the task very difficult.

Could you provide a source where I can have exposure to such kind of mathematics?

Thank you.

Comment: Another term for Gâteaux derivative is [shape derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_optimization), often used in connection with shape optimization.  Are these the sort of problems you are interested in?

Comment: I am not directly doing shape optimization right now. But the work does involve topological derivative applied to structural mechanics. In short, I have a cost functional that includes U mentioned above. Finding the first order optimality is the first step of my task. Any insights??